# Why does Redis have numeric keys for database names and why are these capped to 16?

Tags: redis

I'm curious as to why Redis was designed this way. Is this a performance consideration? Or to simply limit database names?

Answer (score 2):

This is configurable in redis.conf

```
# Set the number of databases. The default database is DB 0, you can select
# a different one on a per-connection basis using SELECT <dbid> where
# dbid is a number between 0 and 'databases'-1
databases 16
```

However, the creator of Redis does not recommend using the SELECT command any longer.